# cURLcpp error while compiling source

Tags: c++, curl, makefile

I am kinda new to c++ and the use of github.
I want to use cURL functionality in c++. Therefore I first forked curlcpp (by JosephP91) from github, and then followed the instructions from its README.txt.

Now I get an Error when executing

```
make # -j2
```

(with or without -j2 makes no difference).

The error:

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/curlcpp.dir/curl_easy.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/.git/curlcpp/src/curl_easy.cpp:6:0:
/home/user/.git/curlcpp/include/curl_easy.h:276:31: error: ‘CURLOPT_OBSOLETE72’ was not declared in this scope
         CURLCPP_DEFINE_OPTION(CURLOPT_OBSOLETE72, long); /* OBSOLETE, do not use! */
                               ^
/home/user/.git/curlcpp/include/curl_easy.h:47:33: note: in definition of macro ‘CURLCPP_DEFINE_OPTION’
     template <> struct option_t<opt> {\
                                 ^
/home/user/.git/curlcpp/include/curl_easy.h:47:36: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     template <> struct option_t<opt> {\
                                    ^
/home/user/.git/curlcpp/include/curl_easy.h:276:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘CURLCPP_DEFINE_OPTION’
         CURLCPP_DEFINE_OPTION(CURLOPT_OBSOLETE72, long); /* OBSOLETE, do not use! */
         ^
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/curlcpp.dir/curl_easy.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/curlcpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Errors 2
```

Thank you guys in advance for helping me!

EDIT:

Output of

```
cmake
```

Output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found suitable version "7.35.0", minimum required is "7.28.0") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/.git/curlcpp/build
```

Comment: can you give cmake output, I tested with JosephP91 repository and it compile just fine for me

Comment: thanks for the quick response! i added the output

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem in ubuntu, I think the problem is the libcurl version, I gonna upgrade and come back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update libcurl fron version 7.35.0 to 7.37.1 on Ubuntu, libcurl 7.31 is available on the utopic repository (http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libcurl4-nss-dev).

You can use apt-get to update by doing:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade libcurl4-nss-dev
```

and then redo cmake and make and it should compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem!
But the first command you provided didn't work for me (no diff with sudo), so i did it this way:
'echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list' (first backup the sources.list)